# Delaying Method Calls and Using Threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, simulation

Let's say I've got this particular piece of code:

```
/****************************************************************/
/* Generate new wave of enrollees                               */
/****************************************************************/
for (int i = 1; i <= new Random().Next(enrolleesExpectedPerMinuteMin, enrolleesExpectedPerMinuteMax) && enrolleesInCampus < enrolleesExpectedTotal; i++)
{
    Enrollee newEnrollee = new Enrollee("ENRL" + i, i);
    listOfEnrollees.Add(newEnrollee);
    enrolleesInCampus = listOfEnrollees.Count;    
    lblEnrolleesInCampusNum.Text = enrolleesInCampus.ToString();
    newEnrollee.enroll(listOfOffices);
}
```

Note that that runs on the tick method of a GUI timer. See, I'm generating `Enrollee` objects. And they have a function called `enroll()` which takes up an argument, which is a list of all the `Office` objects that an `Enrollee` may go to.

Each `Office` object has a list of `ServiceLane` objects. These `ServiceLane` objects have a queue of `Enrollees`; and also, methods called `enqueue()` and `dequeue()`. `enqueue()` simply takes in an argument of type `Enrollee` and adds it to the `enrolleesInLine` list, which speaks of the `Enrollee` objects queued on the `ServiceLane` object. The `dequeue()` method, of course, performs a dequeue, but I need it to perform the dequequeing after a certain varying processing time required by the `ServiceLane`.

The `ServiceLanes` an `Enrollee` goes to is dependent upon the the type of `Enrollee` and the current `Office` they need to get into, therefore, I structured the `enroll()` method like this:

```
public void enroll(List<Office> offices)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case EnrolleeType.NEW_STUDENT:
            // code goes here
            // i.e. :
            // lineInOfficeOne(); // after being attended to/after being serviced
            // lineInOfficeTwo(); // and so on
            break;
        case EnrolleeType.OLD_STUDENT:
            // code goes here 
            break;
        case EnrolleeType.TRANSFEREE: 
            // code goes here
            break;
    }
}
```

With each Enrollee object, I want them to be enqueued on the shortest Service Lane on the current Office they need to get into. And I think I've successfully created a method of that in my Office class --- it returns the ServiceLane object with the shortest queue of enrollees.

However, **problem one** lies in delaying the enqueue method for all Enrollee objects. In real life, an enrollee couldn't get to an office building immediately. The enrollee needs time to go there. I'm planning to use Timers but I'm not really sure how to do this. I tried. LOL. And I could only get a one two three `Enrollee` objects to be enqueued on a `ServiceLane`, when I've already generated hundreds of them. Here's how I did it:

```
public void enroll(List<Office> offices)
{
    switch (walkingSpeed)
    {
        case EnrolleeWalkingSpeed.SLOW: divisor = 5; break;
        case EnrolleeWalkingSpeed.NORMAL: divisor = 3; break;
        case EnrolleeWalkingSpeed.FAST: divisor = 1; break;
    }

    timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;

    /********************************************************************/
    /* REMINDER: Update currentActivity every time the enrollee gets    */
    /*           into the next phase                                    */
    /*           Make an algorithm for choosing the shortest lane       */
    /*           (Office class's findShortestLane())                    */
    /********************************************************************/
    switch (type)
    {
        case EnrolleeType.NEW_STUDENT:
            performActivity(EnrolleeActivity.ACT1, offices.Find(office => office.getName().Equals("Admissions Office")));
            break;
        case EnrolleeType.TRANSFEREEE:
            performActivity(EnrolleeActivity.ACT1, offices.Find(office => office.getName().Equals("Admissions Office")));
            break;
        case EnrolleeType.OLD_STUDENT:
            performActivity(EnrolleeActivity.ACT9, offices.Find(office => office.getName().Equals("Finance Office")));
            break;
    }
}

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (counter % divisor == 0)
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
        currentOffice.findShortestLane().enqueue(this);
        return;
    }

    counter++;
}

public void performActivity(EnrolleeActivity activity, Office office)
{
    this.currentActivity = activity;
    this.currentOffice = office;
    timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

**Problem two** is how to delay the dequeueing process of the `ServiceLane` object. Of course, we need an adequate time to have the request processed. Note, they can only be dequeued one at a time per `ServiceLane`.

**Problem three** is how to let the Enrollee object only be enqueued on another service lane only when the current service lane it's on is finished with the Enrollee object's request (or rather, the processing time has already been reached/has elapsed).

I do know what to search for, hence it's more likely that the title of this question is confusing. I really don't know if I'm gonna use a Thread or a Timer or whatever. Probably a keyword would help. And a snippet of code to show me how I should work these **3 problems** out.

Comment: tl;dr. But it looks like you are confusing real-time and simulated-time. Maybe you should look up "event driven simulation"

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use Task class to achieve your goal.
It has Delay method which accepts delay time in milliseconds and you can set ContinuationTask after that delay time, here is example:

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var delay = Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(_ =>
                           { sw.Stop();
                             return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds; } );

Console.WriteLine("Elapsed milliseconds: {0}", delay.Result);
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) you can find more information about Task class and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873(v=vs.110).aspx) is information about Delay method. Hope this helps.